# Recommendations for References on undecidability of First Order Logic

Tags: lo.logic, undecidability

I am currently reading Computability and Logic by Boolos Burgess Geoffrey for the proof on "undecidability of first order logic". however, I find the notations a bit confusing. Can anyone recommend any resource website link/ video lecture or a book perhaps which will help me understand the proof of undecidability of first order logic? I am a CS student so, I do not want a completely mathematical /philosophical proof. I came across plenty of those on the web.

Comment: I'm confused: you're asking for a *non mathematical* proof of a mathematical result?

Comment: I only asked for an "understandable proof" because I find it confusing to follow complicated mathematical proofs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me clarify one subtle point: first order logic is only undecidable for certain given *languages*. In particular the language $\cal{L}$ that contains **only monadic predicates**, that is, predicates of the form $P(x)$ and no function symbols, is [decidable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monadic_predicate_calculus).

If you allow function symbols or predicates with more than 1 argument, then $\cal{L}$ usually becomes undecidable. The proof involves encoding Turing machines and their computation sequences using the symbols of the logic. Then one adds a **finite** series of axioms $\phi_1,\ldots, \phi_n$, and build a formula $\psi(x,y)$ such that
$$ \phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n\vdash \psi(\overline{n},\overline{m})$$
is *provable* if and only if

> The Turing machine with index $n$ halts in at most $m$ steps on the empty input.

Undecidability of FOL follows, as proving

$$ \vdash \phi_1\wedge\ldots\wedge\phi_n\rightarrow \exists y,\psi(\overline{n},y)$$

is equivalent to determining wether the machine with index $n$ halts.

A detailed description of this proof is given in chapter 4 of Avigad's [lecture notes on computability](http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/avigad/Teaching/candi_notes.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

A Mathematical Introduction to Logic, Second Edition: Herbert B. Enderton